# Arithmetic sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I had this question on a math test and never really understood what the answer to this question was, but had my clues.  I hope one of you out there can help me. I’m also in 10th grade, so my math shouldn’t be that hard.

The question in the test was very long, so I have tried to summarize what they want to get out.

This task is to investigate different kinds of arithmetic sequence of numbers. You must create number sequences that contain four numbers and where the differences must be 5, 3 and optional. So if we take, for example, a sequence of numbers where the difference is 3. The sequence of numbers can read the following 3 6 9 12. With these four numbers you should combine number 1 and number 2, 3 + 6 = 9, the same with the remaining (9 + 12 =  21). Then subtract the sum of the first numbers with the others to find the difference (21-9 = 12). In this way you do with all speech sequences. To the question now: What connection do you find between the difference in the sums and the difference in the sequence of numbers? Based on the results of all your surveys.

I have my thoughts that it may be that the difference is 1/4 of the difference between sum 2 and sum 1. So that the difference times 4 = the differences between sum 2 and sum 1.

Comment: If I have understood you, you want $4$ numbers in the arithmetic progression $\{a, a+d, a+2d, a+3d\}$,yes?  In which case you compute $(a+2d+a+3d)-(a+a+d)=5d-d=4d$.   Is that what you expected?

Comment: @lulu That's how I read it too.

Comment: Almost, they wanted a connection in the arithmetic sequence of numbers between the difference of the sums and the difference of the sequence of numbers. I can not really find this connection except what I wrote under the question. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Well, the computation I showed you reveals that the "difference between the sums" and "the difference between consecutive terms"  differ by a multiplicative factor of $4$.

Comment: Ah, okay now I see. Thanks so much for your help.